# NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification replacement?

Tags: core-data, icloud, deprecated

Having just installed XCode 8, I discover that NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification becomes deprecated. The warning message sends me to the documentation.

Apple documentation indeed marks all ubiquity symbols as deprecated, but I can't find any documentation saying how to replace them properly.

Any link ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no replacement; Core Data's iCloud integration is deprecated and has no direct replacement. The alternative is to use CloudKit, but that requires changing the app's design since the API is very different.

Core Data's iCloud support should continue working for now though. As explained in an [Apple dev forums post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/144638#144638) (login required) from an Apple engineer, it should keep working "for the foreseeable future". What that means specifically is impossible to say but typically deprecated stuff keeps working for a long time.

Anyone wanting to keep using this style of syncing while avoiding deprecations should take a look at [Ensembles](http://www.ensembles.io).

Comment: I was afraid of that... The thing is, CloudKit is not quite like CoreData/iCloud integration. I guess many CoreData model to CloudKit model glue code to write. In my view a layer is missing between data transfer (CloudKit) and app data modelling (CoreData). I hope Apple is on its way to fill this gap. Any link where this topic would be addressed ?

Comment: Thanks ! I also found this https://nickharris.wordpress.com/2016/02/09/cloudkit-core-data-nsoperations-introduction/